# Corpus of user interactions for AI?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, chat, corpus

Is there any corpus that contains anonymized user interactions? As in, many call services and online chat support things have notes that you "may be recorded for the...etc...", so has anyone collected a large sample of human dialogue just as a reference/testing ground for new AI techniques?
Sorry if this is in the wrong site,
Matthew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean a *corpus*. Here is a corpus which is not drawn from support chats, but from general chats:

[NPS Chat](http://faculty.nps.edu/cmartell/NPSChat.htm). Download from [NLTK](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nltk_data/index.xml). Consists of 10,567 posts gathered from various online chat services. It is XML and POS tagged.